# Understanding the below code

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, performselector, dispatch-async

I just tried the below code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self taskB];
    });

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(taskA) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

This `taskA` and `taskB` executing a `NSLog` and nothing else. Now here as `taskB` written first but `taskA` executing first. Even I change the order still `performSelectorOnMainThread` executing first. And for each case my console shows

```
2015-03-17 16:44:35.157 TestProject[9346:191978] Task A
2015-03-17 16:44:35.283 TestProject[9346:191978] Task B
```

Can anybody help me to understand what is happening here. And why `performSelectorOnMainThread` execute first?

Answer (score 3):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self taskB];
    });
```

In this code you are using `dispatch_async` that tells the compiler **not to halt** the further execution for the code written within it,So the compiler continues to execute the `performSelectorOnMainThread` and after that the compiler thinks about the `dispatch`.
Read More about [Dispatch(GCD) here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1).

Answer (score 2):

You are initiating an asynchronous task with dispatch_async which does not guarantee that it will be executed immediately.

But on the other hand you are telling your main queue (which is generally default queue on your lifecycle) that you want to execute task A.

So whenever the code runs the block is going to be skipped asynchronously and continue performing task A. After that task ends task B is going to be initiated asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this page, addresses the same topic

https://blackpixel.com/writing/2013/11/performselectoronmainthread-vs-dispatch-async.html